# Android C2DM - What happens if registration ID gets refreshed

Tags: android, android-c2dm

in my Application I'am currently sending a registration intent to the google server everytime the app starts. I get a different registration ID everytime I do that, though the old ones still work. I guess thats not a good way to do it.
So I thought that I should send the registration intent only once - at the first start of the app. Now my question, if google refreshes the registration ID, do they inform the application about that? Whithout my app sending anything to them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have an C2DM and my solution was to register on every start of the  application, but when using when sending the C2DM messages through my server delete the entry of the database if the error code was a **InvalidRegistration**

So if a device was registered multiple times, I only send one invalid message.

Comment: Ye that surely works, but I want to minimize the requests to the server. Its a business server where the mobile applications have only a minor role. So I can't send requests to the server all the time.

Comment: You can then save the registration Id as a preference or in a database. and delete when you receive the REGISTER intent with an unregistered extra parameter.

Comment: Yes sure, but the question is: Does the c2dm server inform the app when the registration id changes. I dont want to send registration intents all the time if its not necessary.

Comment: Yes, see http://code.google.com/android/c2dm/ at the section Handling Registration Results.

Comment: So I could do what I described in my initial post? Register once and then wait for google to send registration ids to the app.

Comment: You can do it, but you must save the registration id when you receive the first Registration Intent. And be aware that if the registration_id is not more "alive" you will receive a REGISTER intent with the  extra parameter "unregistered"

Comment: Ok, thank you very much. Last question: Is there any knowledge about the time a registration id is valid? Couldnt find detailed information about that in the google documentation.

Answer (score 0):

You could ping the business server if the registration have changed. You could ask for a registration update once a day.

Meaning that you can save the registration in the phone using the preferences and then only stream to the server if it has changed.

Although I am pretty sure the registration changes every time you ask for a new one. Maybe there's a way to check if a registration is still valid?